# how to set different onclick listener for each button populated by a recyclerview

Tags: java, android, button, adapter, cardview

I was modifying this code > https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/viewpagercards to fit my own app but as you can find from the source code there is no method to handle onclick event for each buttons, My plan is to add different intent for each button clicked on the cardviews so please help me out I'm a noob/beginner to android and java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it by using `Switch statement` based on positions in `onBindViewHolder`. For example:

```
Switch(position){
case 0:
//Button No.1
break;
case 1:
//Button No.2
break;
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can check the condition in the onclick of button in recyclerview adapter onBindViewHolder with respect to position of button. you can use like if(position == 1) {-- do something --} , if(position == 2) {-- do other thing --} inside your button click.

Answer (score 0):

You need create custom adapter in your library below code is example :

```
   public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<Category> list;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<Category> list){
        this.list = list;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_category, null);
        return new CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        viewHolder.btnOne.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnItemClickListener{
// do something
});
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Button btnOne, btnTwo;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            btnOne = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_one);
            btnTwo = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_two);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: excuse me custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

Ge your buttons reference & put each onClick listener inside your onBindViewHolder() method.